# Spring Tool Suite 3.7: Where is the option for Creating a Spring MVC project

Tags: spring

[image][image]I am starting to learn Spring. I downloaded STS 3.7 and tried to find out a Spring MVC tutorial on the web. However, most of the tutorials i found are for STS version lower than 3.7 and they all start with Create new project -> Spring Template -> MVC. 
However, When i check my New Project options (in my STST 3.7), i only see two Spring options -  "Spring Project" and "Spring Starter Project". 
1. Under Spring Project, i can see one of the templates(closest match to a web project) named as: Simple Spring web maven, and i tried creating the project using that template, but it did not create the same folder structure as was shown in tutorials. For instance, it did not create a WEB-INF folder and hence no servlet-context.xml
2. Under Spring Starter Project, i could see a lot of options, one of them was Web and one was WS, but none of them could produce similar folder structure as shown in tutorials like the one here: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide so again no servlet-context.xml

Could someone kindly explain what am i missing here. Should i downgrade to a lower version of STS so it matches tutorials and i can see the same options as shown in tutorial? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try with File>New Project>Spring>Spring Project and then you can select a template from the template´s section.

Comment: Hi Benja, when i try to do that only option i get from templates list are: "Simple Projects" -> 1. Simple Java 2. Simple Spring Maven 3. Simple Spring Web Maven. I don't see an option as MVC at all. Would you have an idea if i am missing any plugin or need to download the template? By the way as a workaround, i used eclipse Luna to create a Spring MVC project for the time being.

Comment: @JavaTec you are talking about simple projects folder but i am talking about two files on this section which name are "Simple Spring Utility Project" and "Spring MVC Project". Try scroll down to see them ;)

Comment: Hi Benja, Thank you. I have added an image to my original question, which shows all the template options i have. Please let me know if you think i am missing anything.

Comment: I am not sure but probably you don´t have installed all the modules. Can you post your eclipse installation details?

Comment: hey Benja by eclipse installation details, i hope you mean STS installation details. Here they are: `Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290649
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) ` Snapshot with more details added in the original question

Comment: i don´t have more ideas about this subject :( @89n3ur0n

Comment: I could not resolve that issue either. i left Spring Tool Suite and used eclipse rather.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Project with Spring Legacy 
click next to Choose Spring MVC as the Template

The below resource may be helpful
http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial